# Adding an external network makes MySQL database unreachable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having some problems with a docker-compose file and haven't been able to figure out why.
This is the file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0.0
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ******
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ******
        volumes:
           - /opt/mysql_auth:/var/lib/mysql
        restart: always
    auth:
        image: authdotnetcore
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Auth/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: always
        networks:
            - web
networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

The auth service is a ASP.NET Core application which connect to the MySQL database using db as server on the appsettings. The compose file works fine if I remove the external web network, but when I add it I get a: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

It should work because the compose default network linking the containers is still created.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docker-compose documentation, Please find more details [Here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).

DB service was missing the networks section:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: 'mysql:8.0.0'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: null
            MYSQL_DATABASE: null
        volumes:
            - '/opt/mysql_auth:/var/lib/mysql'
        restart: always
        networks:
            - web
    auth:
        image: authdotnetcore
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Auth/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - db
        restart: always
        links:
            - db
        networks:
            - web

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Comment: The output is the correct one, but I need the web network to work with Traafik. When I add it the connection to the database ceases to exist.

Comment: With that add the links: key-value pair. as specified above in the answer box. The link will connect to the DB.

Comment: I have the same error even if I add a link to the db. If I remove the web network it works fine.

Comment: How you are connecting to the database in the auth server. What did you specify?

Comment: "DefaultConnection": "server=db;database=******;uid=root;pwd=******; default command timeout=600;"

Comment: Please check the updated docker-compose file. network for db was missing.